# skleaarn GridSearchCV metrics

Tags: scikit-learn, gridsearchcv

I used the following code to initialize and fit GridSearchCV metrics, I followed the signature of the function but I get stubborn error as follows

```
from sklearn.model_selection import GridSearchCV
from sklearn.metrics import precision_score, recall_score, make_scorer
grid = GridSearchCV(
LogisticRegression(max_iter=1000),
param_grid={'class_weight':[{0:1,1:v}for v in np.linspace(1,20,30)]},
scoring= {'precision':make_scorer(precision_score), 'recall':make_scorer(recall_score)},
refit('precision'),
cv=4
return_train_score=True,
)
grid.fit(X,y)
results = grid.cv_results_
```

I get error
File "C:\Users\Hello\AppData\Local\Temp\ipykernel_9720\1667363909.py", line 12
)
^
SyntaxError: positional argument follows keyword argument

Init signature:
GridSearchCV(
estimator,
param_grid,
*,
scoring=None,
n_jobs=None,
refit=True,
cv=None,
verbose=0,
pre_dispatch='2*n_jobs',
error_score=nan,
return_train_score=False,
)
Please advise.

Comment: `refit='precision'`, not `refit('precision')`